# Performing the same operation on multiple arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a list of arrays labelled P1,P2,P3,..,P12. They're all 1017x1017 matrices full of NaNs and unwanted gaps where there is no data. I know how to fix this for each individual "P" and stack them into a single column vector:

```
P1(isnan(P1)) = 0 ;
c1 = nonzeros(P1);
P2(isnan(P2)) = 0;
c2 = nonzeros(P2);
C = vertcat(c1,c2);
```

and so on... where c1 is a column of values from P1 etc.

I've tried doing this:

```
for k = 1:12
 A = ['P',num2str(k)];
 B = ['c',num2str(k)];
 A(isnan(A)) = 0;
 B = nonzeros(A);
 cTot = vertcat(B);
 end
```

but it didn't work at all... any ideas?

Comment: Don't use such variable names. Instead of `P1`...`P12` use a cell array or better use one 3D-Matrix `P`.

Comment: Details: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for k = 1:12

    A = evalin('caller', ['P',num2str(k)]);
    B = evalin('caller', ['c',num2str(k)]);

    % ... Do what you have to do with A and B

end
```

NB: You should replace `'caller'` by `'base'` if the code is inside a script instead of a function.

---

**Edit**

To be complete, here is a solution with `eval`. As outlined in the comments, `eval` (or `evalin`) should be avoided as much as possible, but in your case there are not so many alternatives. The following solution also stacks the values of `P1`, ... `P12` into a single array `C`:

```
% Prepare result array
C = [];

for k = 1:12

    % Get A from Px
    eval(['A = P' num2str(k) ';']);

    % Set NaN as zeros
    A(isnan(A)) = 0;

    % Concatenate non-zero values
    C = [C ; nonzeros(A)];

end

% C contains the desired result
```

NB: By the way, changing `NaN` to zeros is a pretty bad habit, a `NaN` should stay a `NaN`.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of how to get the changed values back into the ill-named variables. (You should be able to use `assignin`, but you'll be much happier in the long run without ever touching these two functions.)

Comment: Why `evalin`? You don't need to access caller or base workspace for this purpose. `eval` might be acceptable but should be avoided as well.

Comment: This helped loads thanks crazy rat. It outputs a slightly smaller column of non-zero values than my long way (at the top of my question) but seems to do the job

Comment: Well, if you are happy with the solution you can vote for it, or better, mark the question as solved such that the community knows you no longer need help on this.